# Read Mercurial Response from a Command Line

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I am building an app where the commit push happens in the back ground. I am able to commit - push to remote server. 
Now i am going to make my app do the commit - push asynchronously. So whenever i do a push in the command line i need to get a response (saying it is successfully pushed or not) 
As of now this is the message for successful push

```
pushing to http://...
1 changesets found
remote:adding changesets
remote:adding manifests
remote adding file changes
remote added 1 changesets with 1 changes to 1 files
```

It would be really helpful if i got something like successful or failed or 0 / 1

**One of my friends told me to run echo %errorvariable% immediately after you execute the push command
That is returning 0 for success (successful push or no changes) and -1 for error. 
Is this  correct?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Windows command prompt, the command to echo the return code would actually be `echo %errorlevel%`.  I just did a quick test and got three values of `%errorlevel%`:

- Successful push returned 0
- No changes to push returned 1
- An error in pushing gave 255 (I pushed to a non-existent URL for this test)

Depending upon how you launch Mercurial, you should be able to get access to the return code without doing `echo %errorlevel%`.  You'd need to look into the documentation for the function that you are calling to launch it for details.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.. 
When i tested , i got 0 for no changes and a -1 for error
And by the way i am running these commands via CMD

Comment: I believe that Mercurial changed some of its return codes recently so maybe you're on an older version.  My test was with version 2.1.